# This `div` call produces: Html (String -> Msg) But the type annotation on `view` says it should be: Html Msg

Tags: elm

I'm currently learning elm, I just stumbled on this problem where the div returns a Html (String -> Msg) instead of Html Msg.

error message I'm receiving

This `div` call produces:

```
Html (String -> Msg)
```

But the type annotation on `view` says it should be:

```
Html Msg
```

```
type alias Model =
   {
       firstNum: String,
       secondNum: String,
       answer: String
   }

init: Model 
init = { firstNum = "",
        secondNum = "",
        answer = ""}

type Msg =
    Add String| Minus String

update: Msg -> Model -> Model
update msg model =
    case msg of 
        Add  x -> { model | answer = x}
        Minus  y -> { model | answer = y}

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div [] 
    [
        input [ placeholder "Text to reverse", value model.firstNum] [],
        button [onClick Add] [text "add"],
        div [] [text model.answer]
    ]


main = 
  Browser.sandbox
  { init = init,
    update = update,
    view = view
  }
```

Comment: Haven't time to make this into an answer or investigate how to fix, but in short your error is that you have `onClick Add` when it should be `onClick (Add x)` for some `x`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You define the `Msg` type as

```
type Msg =
    Add String| Minus String
```

with `Add` taking a `String` argument, but when you use it here:

```
button [onClick Add] [text "add"],
```

you're not giving it any argument at all.

The underlying issue seems to be that your mental model of the Elm Architecture is wrong. You seem to consider messages as "operations" or function calls rather than events, where `Add` is a function that takes an argument to apply to the model.

You should instead consider a message as a description of what triggered it. Instead of `Add String`, you might call it `AddButtonClicked`, with no arguments (in this case). Then have the update function do what it should based on what's in the model alone, which I'm guessing is an arithmetic operation on `firstNum` and `secondNum`.

But you're also not populating those fields. To do so you need to use the `onInput` event, which does ask for a message that takes a `String`. You might add a new message `FirstNumChanged String` for example, then use it with `input` like this:

```
input [ placeholder "Text to reverse", onInput FirstNumChanged, value model.firstNum] [],
```

I'll leave it to you to figure out how to handle it in `update`.